# Выводит только первую строку

Tags: php, mysqli

> Пытаюсь заполнить таблицу значениями из БД. Но выводятся только первые значения.

```
<?php
for ($j = 0; $j<7; $j++) {
$day = $days[$j];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `time` FROM `table` WHERE `date`='$day'");
$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();                        
  for ($i = 0; $i<count($rows); $i++) {
     echo 'document.getElementById("dynamic"). 
      rows['.$i+2).'].cells['.$j.'].firstChild.data = "'.$rows["time"].'";';
  }      
 }
```

Comment: `$rows[$i]["time"]` ?

Comment: Так вообще ничего не выдает. Походу у меня почему-то из БД вообще только по одному значению подтягивает.

Comment: посмотри в доки как делается `fetch_assoc`. Именно он делается в цикле https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples

Comment: Зачем первый цикл? Что это вообще такое? Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, задачу с описанием.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам $mysqli->query возвращает resultset, который необходимо перебирать в цикле. Например, вот так:

```
<?php
for ($j = 0; $j<7; $j++) {
  $day = $days[$j];
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `time` FROM `table` WHERE `date`='$day'");
  while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                        
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($rows); $i++) {
      echo 'document.getElementById("dynamic").rows['.$i+2).'].cells['.$j.'].firstChild.data = "'.$rows["time"].'";';
    }
  }
}
```